# how to distinguish debug and release executables on linux

Tags: linux, debugging, release

I have a program with debug and release version. Here's their size:

```
[root@build]$ ll -h debug release 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  12M Dec 29 11:49 debug
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3.6M Dec 29 11:51 release
```

I want to distinguish debug version and release version on linux with just one or two commands, but i don't know how to do that. When I compile my programs with option -g, debug version was created. And here's command ***readelf -S debug*** output:

```
There are 41 section headers, starting at offset 0xa0bb88:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000400238  00000238
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000400254  00000254
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .hash             HASH             0000000000400278  00000278
       00000000000132f0  0000000000000004   A       4     0     8
  [ 4] .dynsym           DYNSYM           0000000000413568  00013568
       0000000000042fd8  0000000000000018   A       5     1     8
  [ 5] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000456540  00056540
       00000000000dfa70  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 6] .gnu.version      VERSYM           0000000000535fb0  00135fb0
       0000000000005952  0000000000000002   A       4     0     2
  [ 7] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          000000000053b908  0013b908
       0000000000000250  0000000000000000   A       5     9     8
  [ 8] .rela.dyn         RELA             000000000053bb58  0013bb58
       0000000000000c78  0000000000000018   A       4     0     8
  [ 9] .rela.plt         RELA             000000000053c7d0  0013c7d0
       0000000000002958  0000000000000018   A       4    11     8
  [10] .init             PROGBITS         000000000053f128  0013f128
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [11] .plt              PROGBITS         000000000053f140  0013f140
       0000000000001ba0  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000540ce0  00140ce0
       0000000000136368  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .fini             PROGBITS         0000000000677048  00277048
       000000000000000e  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [14] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000677080  00277080
       0000000000024480  0000000000000000   A       0     0     64
  [15] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         000000000069b500  0029b500
       00000000000111ec  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [16] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         00000000006ac6f0  002ac6f0
       000000000005058c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [17] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS         00000000006fcc7c  002fcc7c
       000000000000a850  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [18] .tdata            PROGBITS         00000000009074d0  003074d0
       0000000000000004  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
  [19] .tbss             NOBITS           00000000009074d8  003074d4
       000000000001b4d8  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
  [20] .preinit_array    PREINIT_ARRAY    00000000009074d8  003074d8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .ctors            PROGBITS         00000000009074e0  003074e0
       0000000000000158  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [22] .dtors            PROGBITS         0000000000907638  00307638
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .jcr              PROGBITS         0000000000907648  00307648
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [24] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS         0000000000907680  00307680
       0000000000004990  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [25] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          000000000090c010  0030c010
       0000000000000240  0000000000000010  WA       5     0     8
  [26] .got              PROGBITS         000000000090c250  0030c250
       0000000000000310  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [27] .got.plt          PROGBITS         000000000090c560  0030c560
       0000000000000de0  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [28] .data             PROGBITS         000000000090d340  0030d340
       0000000000000fe0  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [29] .bss              NOBITS           000000000090e340  0030e320
       0000000000c18a38  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [30] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0030e320
       000000000000003e  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [31] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0030e35e
       00000000000200b0  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [32] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0032e40e
       000000000033aded  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [33] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  006691fb
       00000000000296ae  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [34] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  006928a9
       0000000000068038  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [35] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  006fa8e1
       00000000001afb89  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [36] .debug_loc        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  008aa46a
       000000000010b830  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [37] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  009b5c9a
       0000000000055d70  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [38] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00a0ba0a
       000000000000017b  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [39] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00a0c5c8
       00000000000562f8  0000000000000018          40   3277     8
  [40] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00a628c0
       00000000000fa11b  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

And without -g option, release version created, here's ***readelf -S release*** outputs:

```
    There are 39 section headers, starting at offset 0x3290b8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000400238  00000238
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000400254  00000254
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .hash             HASH             0000000000400278  00000278
       0000000000008558  0000000000000004   A       4     0     8
  [ 4] .dynsym           DYNSYM           00000000004087d0  000087d0
       0000000000019f98  0000000000000018   A       5     1     8
  [ 5] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000422768  00022768
       000000000003d80b  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 6] .gnu.version      VERSYM           000000000045ff74  0005ff74
       00000000000022a2  0000000000000002   A       4     0     2
  [ 7] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          0000000000462218  00062218
       0000000000000200  0000000000000000   A       5     8     8
  [ 8] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000462418  00062418
       0000000000000840  0000000000000018   A       4     0     8
  [ 9] .rela.plt         RELA             0000000000462c58  00062c58
       00000000000020e8  0000000000000018   A       4    11     8
  [10] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000464d40  00064d40
       0000000000000018  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [11] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000464d58  00064d58
       0000000000001600  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000466360  00066360
       00000000000e6a28  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .fini             PROGBITS         000000000054cd88  0014cd88
       000000000000000e  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [14] .rodata           PROGBITS         000000000054cdc0  0014cdc0
       000000000001d3f0  0000000000000000   A       0     0     64
  [15] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         000000000056a1b0  0016a1b0
       00000000000068e4  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [16] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000570a98  00170a98
       0000000000025e7c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [17] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS         0000000000596914  00196914
       0000000000009914  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [18] .tbss             NOBITS           00000000007a0228  001a0228
       0000000000000950  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
  [19] .ctors            PROGBITS         00000000007a0228  001a0228
       0000000000000130  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .dtors            PROGBITS         00000000007a0358  001a0358
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .jcr              PROGBITS         00000000007a0368  001a0368
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [22] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS         00000000007a0380  001a0380
       0000000000003bd0  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [23] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          00000000007a3f50  001a3f50
       0000000000000210  0000000000000010  WA       5     0     8
  [24] .got              PROGBITS         00000000007a4160  001a4160
       0000000000000158  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [25] .got.plt          PROGBITS         00000000007a42b8  001a42b8
       0000000000000b10  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [26] .data             PROGBITS         00000000007a4e00  001a4e00
       00000000000007c0  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [27] .bss              NOBITS           00000000007a55c0  001a55c0
       0000000000002038  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
  [28] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  001a55c0
       000000000000003e  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [29] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  001a55fe
       0000000000000e10  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [30] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  001a640e
       00000000000a1d76  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [31] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00248184
       000000000000b09d  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [32] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00253221
       00000000000113c8  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [33] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  002645e9
       000000000001731a  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [34] .debug_loc        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0027b903
       00000000000923ad  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [35] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0030dcb0
       000000000001b2a0  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [36] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00328f50
       0000000000000165  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [37] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00329a78
       0000000000021048  0000000000000018          38   1203     8
  [38] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  0034aac0
       000000000004b633  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

The two condition differs in the number of section headers. It seems that i can't distinguish the two version with this command. Any other solutions ?

Comment: Are you sure the second one is built without `-g`? It contains `debug` sections which should not be produced unless `-g` was specified.

Comment: There is no such thing as "debug executable". Each individual object file may be compiled with or without debug information. So an executable may be 37% debug, 63% release, so to speak.

Comment: If you strip the symbol table and debug sections with `strip` or linking with the `-s` option, then the `file` command will tell you easily if the executable is stripped or not.  But if the executable is not stripped, then like @n.m. says, the executable may contain some, but not all possible, debug information.   How one could tell that there exists a function parameter to some function not identified in the debug info sounds like a difficult problem even if one were willing to code a complex algorithm to solve it!  I suggest stripping the release executables to make it easy!

Comment: If that's the case, then the title that how to distinguish an executable with or without -g option may be better @TrentP

Comment: But -g is not a binary option for the executable, either not there or all there.  It's not even an option when linking the executable. See the ld docs: -g is ignored.  It's an option for each object file used to make the executable.  You may have 0% to 100% of possible debug info.  0% can be detected via `file` output and looking for ", stripped".  Detecting 1%-99% vs 100% seems virtually impossible.  In your example, both your executables have debug info!  They were both, at least partially, compiled with -g.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do a rebuild, try adding `LOCALVERSION=build_release` or `LOCALVERSION=build_debug` to the make command line for release and debug builds respectively. You should then be able to find these strings with:

```
strings <kernel image> | fgrep build_
```

You might need to make sure `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` is not defined in your .config file.

It can be hard to know what the build intention was by looking at the produced image, unless some string has deliberately been put there. Which is what I tried to accomplish above.

Answer (score 0):

```
readelf -S <image name> | grep debug
```

if image is built in debug, it will output something like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PrwI.png)

otherwise it is built in release.